How to display batch apex results on LWC component
I am developing a Lightning Web Component (LWC) designed to display invoice data for the current period and year-to-date (YTD). The challenge is handling over 50,000 invoice records for YTD calculations, which is causing a 500001 error due to the large volume of records. I haven't tried calling batch apex on LWC before.
To manage this, I've considered using Batch Apex, but I am uncertain how to efficiently use the results in my LWC without storing the data in a custom object or using platform cache, both of which I prefer to avoid for this use case. YTD Values keep changing based on combo box selection. Parameters I'm passing are login user Id and selectedrolename.
Here are my specific concerns and constraints:
Avoiding Persistent Storage: I do not want to use a custom object or platform cache to store the batch processing results due to concerns over scalability and data storage limitations.
Integration of Batch Apex with LWC: How can I integrate Batch Apex results directly into my LWC without storing the results?
This is my start and execute method
   // Define the query to retrieve YTD invoices for the selected users
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT User__r.Name, Invoice_Value__c, CurrencyIsoCode 
            FROM Invoice_Item__c 
            WHERE User__c IN :userList
            AND MFG_Pro_Due_Date__c >= :fiscalYearStartDate 
            AND MFG_Pro_Due_Date__c <= :fiscalYearEndDate
        ]);
    }

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Invoice_Item__c> scope) {
    Map<String, Decimal> conversionRates = new Map<String, Decimal>();
    for (CurrencyType ct : [SELECT IsoCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType]) {
        conversionRates.put(ct.IsoCode, ct.ConversionRate);
    }

    for (Invoice_Item__c invoice : scope) {
        String userName = invoice.User__r.Name;
        Decimal invoiceValue = invoice.Invoice_Value__c;
        String currencyCode = invoice.CurrencyIsoCode;

        // Convert the invoice value to the corporate currency if necessary
        if (currencyCode != corporateCurrency) {
            invoiceValue = invoiceValue * (conversionRates.containsKey(currencyCode) ? conversionRates.get(currencyCode) : 1);
        }

        // Add to YTD total for the user
        if (!ytdInvoiceTotals.containsKey(userName)) {
            ytdInvoiceTotals.put(userName, 0);
        }
        ytdInvoiceTotals.put(userName, ytdInvoiceTotals.get(userName) + invoiceValue);

        // Aggregate the invoice value to team total
        teamYTDTotalInvoice += invoiceValue;

        // Check if the invoice is for the logged-in user and update their total
        if (invoice.User__c.equals(loginUserId)) {
            userYTDTotalInvoice += invoiceValue;
        }
    }
   }



To clarify, the problem you're trying to solve via batch apex is displaying a larger set of records in the LWC than otherwise possible?

I'm trying to display teamtotal value from batch calculations based on logged in user and selected role name.

This is a very broad question and is likely to be closed without narrowing down your question to a single problem. Please edit your question to provide more clarity. What part of your code is attempting to do what you're talking about? Why are you focusing on batch apex? This sounds like an X-Y problem to me.  Isn't this exactly what Platform Cache was created for?  To store the results of long running or complex operations.
